# Using grep/find combination to find the usages of a function or a struct

Tags: c, linux, grep

I am wondering how I can effectively find the usages of a function/structure in the files using `find & grep` combination.

For example, I have source code for `git` on my machine. If you look at the `commit.h`, you can see `commit` structure is defined like,

```
struct commit {
    struct object object;
    void *util;
    unsigned int indegree;
    unsigned long date;
    struct commit_list *parents;
    struct tree *tree;
    char *buffer;
};
```

I am interested to find out from where this structure is initialized and how are they initializing buffer. First I tried,

```
grep -rn "(struct commit)" .
```

This gave me a file which has this structure initialization. Now I need to find out where the `buffer` variable which is a member of this structure is initialized.

```
grep -rn "buffer" .
```

returnes a lot of results and tough to find out where it is used.

So I am wondering, how do you find out the usages of a symbol effectively? I am not talking about what an IDE provides but with using standard linux tools like `grep` and `find`. How do you manage to hack into a big codebase and understand how it works?

Answer (score 10):

Have you evaluated cscope or ctags for the purpose ?

Both of them work well with both vim and emacs. The main ability that they provide you is to lookup the definitions of a symbol in your source code that may be used and defined at different files.

I personally use cscope http://cscope.sourceforge.net/cscope_vim_tutorial.html and it works beautifully for me to dig into the code.

Comment: Thanks. It sounds promising. I will take a look.

Answer (score 2):

Finding references to a member of a struct is easier if the member has a less generic name than "buffer". But you knew that.

Using just a modern version of grep, you can find references to all members named "buffer" accessed through a pointer as:

```
grep --recursive --include=\*.c "->buffer"
```

or accessed as a member of a local instance as:

```
grep --recursive --include=\*.c "\.buffer"
```

The sensible inclusion of --recursive in GNU grep makes learning to correctly use find over a source tree much less important. (Also, I think I've got the quoting right... but beware of shell quoting in an example typed off the cuff.)

I would concur with the recommendation to learn about tools like ctags, and how they integrate with your editor of choice. Both emacs and vim are a lot more powerful than they look at first glance.

Answer (score 2):

[Kscope](http://sourceforge.net/projects/kscope/) is cscope + ctags with a graphical user interface. Very convenient if you are not a big fan of vi or emacs. Since it was originally targeted at kernel source navigation, it has no problem handling large projects.

Answer (score 0):

You could always build git with the GCC debug flag enabled (-g) and use [GDB](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/).  You could set a break point in the initialization function and backtrace from there.  That should give you a better idea about what is happening in the callstack without having to follow a bunch of function declarations etc.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from cscope and ctags as mentioned by Kisalay.

You can use try [id-utils](http://www.gnu.org/software/idutils/). There are may VIM plugins to use idutils from VIM.
It crates a ID file from you source code and very fast in searching.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is [GNU GLOBAL](http://www.gnu.org/software/global/global.html) which will show all the uses of classes and functions in a cross-referenced manner, eg look at the analysis of the [linux kernel](http://www.tamacom.com/tour/kernel/linux/)